# Moment.d.ts errors in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

We imported the AdminLTE bootstrap admin theme for an MVC project in Visual Studio, and the Moment.js plugin is showing 91 errors in the Error List window, all specific to the `Moment.d.ts` file.

Obviously Moment.js is a mature plugin, so there won't be anything to fix.  Do the errors indicate that the plugin has been included incorrectly, or is this simply something I can ignore, and how would I prevent the errors from showing up?

*Note:* there don't seem to be any browser-level JavaScript errors relating to Moment.js, so I assume it's working correctly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end I just commented out the whole `moment.d.ts` file